# ValueError: not a valid sha256_crypt hash when verifying password but it was not encrypt in mysql database

Tags: python, flask-login

I can't find what wrong happen in this code. Help me to find out the solution.[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sU2Q.png)
Why sha256_crypt.verify(password,possw_data) give wrong? I can't find the solution.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
import MySQLdb
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
  if request.method == "POST":
     username = request.form["username"]
    password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(request.form['password'])
    cursor = mydb.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username ='"+ username +"'")
    userdata = cursor.fetchone()

    if userdata is None:
        flash("Incorrect username","danger")
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        for possw_data in userdata:
            if sha256_crypt.verify(password,possw_data):
                flash("You are now login","success")
                return redirect(url_for('profile'))
            else:
                flash("Incorrect password!")
                return render_template("login.html")

  return render_template("login.html")
```

Comment: you have selected the username but not the password column.

Comment: What is the type of `password` and `posw_data`? Please check the type needed by `sha256_crypt.verify`. As per the [doc](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html), it should be a unix hash in the format mentioned in their code. Please check if your `pows_data` is a valid unix hash.